# VS 2010 & SQL Server 2008: I'm trying to backup my database (.mdf file) but don't know how

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, mdf

I have a .mdf database I created in my App_Data directory for my site.  I'm not sure how to back it up however. I was going to just copy/paste it to another drive but not sure that's actually backing it up as securely as I'd like.  I know SQL Server 2008 has a back up option that creates a .bak file and everything but I can't seem to get my database to attach there and then be able to do that.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up Sql Server Managment Studio (SSMS). Attach your database by selecting the mdf file. It should pull in your ldf log file as well. Then you will be able to right click the database in object explorer and under tasks you can backup your database into a bak file.

Comment: Thanks! This worked, but I should note two errors I ran into while doing this. 1. Had to run SQL Server Management Studio in Administration Mode. 2. Had to copy the database files from my NAS unit. (Had to copy them to my local drive). Thanks! Also what all do I need to restore the backup now? .mdf, .ldf, and .bak or just .bak ? Thanks!

Comment: Just the .bak file. You can restore it as any database you so desire.